# Ubuntu 12.10 won't allow admin privileges when password is set to None

Tags: password

I have the drivers for wireless in Ubuntu 12.0 for my Inspirion 1521,  I set the password to "None" to be required whenever I start my computer.  However now I cannot run the drivers without a password.  Nor can I create one in the settings.  How do I run the drivers if I  Ubuntu no longer recognizes me as admin?

Comment: Well, no password, no admin rights, makes sense to me. Not really sure what you've expected.

Comment: Did you ever set a password? (Before selecting "None.") If so, what happens when you enter that password when prompted to do so to install drivers? Even if you've set things up so you don't need a password to log on, you should still *have* a password configured. If you do not, or if you don't remember it, you can reset it. See [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) Please let us know if this doesn't help, since we'll probably close this question as a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you have to reset your account's password.

Reboot your computer and in the Grub menu, choose recovery mode. In the recovery menu choose **root shell**.

Remount the partition as read/write with: `mount -rw -o remount /`

Now you can reset your password with: `passwd username`. change username with the name for your account.

Reboot your computer and you're done.